# Annotation Processor, generating a compiler error

Tags: java, annotations, javac

I'm trying to create a custom annotation that, for example, ensures that a field or method is both `public` and `final`, and would generate a compile time error if the field or method is not both `public` and `final`, as in these examples:

```
// Compiles
@PublicFinal
public final int var = 2;

// Compiles
@PublicFinal
public final void myMethod {}

// Compile time error
@PublicFinal
private final int fail = 2;
```

So far, I've made both the custom annotation interface:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface PublicFinal { }
```

and `Processor`:

```
import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.lang.model.element.Modifier;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import java.util.Set;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("PublicFinal")
public class PubicFinalProcessor extends AbstractProcessor
{
    @Override
    public boolean process(
            Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
            RoundEnvironment roundEnv)
    {
        for (TypeElement typeElement : annotations)
        {
            Set<Modifier> modifiers = typeElement.getModifiers();

            if (!modifiers.contains(Modifier.FINAL)
                    || !modifiers.contains(Modifier.PUBLIC))
            {
                // Compile time error.
                // TODO How do I raise an error?
            }
        }

        // All PublicFinal annotations are handled by this Processor.
        return true;
    }
}
```

As hinted by the `TODO`, I do not know how to generate the compile time error. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) of Processor makes it clear that I should not be throwing an exception,

> If a processor throws an uncaught exception, the tool may cease other active annotation processors.

It goes on to describe what happens when an error condition is raised, but now *how* to raise an error condition.

Question: how do I raise an error condition such that it generates a compile time error?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You probably want `processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Kind.ERROR, "method wasn't public and final", element)`.

[Messager:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Messager.html) "Printing a message with an error kind will raise an error."