# How to implement something similar to the @Override java annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, java-8

With this jdk code in `../java/lang/Override.java`,

```
package java.lang;
import java.lang.annotation.*;
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)

public @interface Override {
}
```

having just annotation declaration, java compiler is intelligent enough to detect error(compile time):

`The method toString123() of type Example must override or implement a supertype method`

in the below problem code.

```
package annotationtype;

public class Example {

    @Override public String toString() {
       return "Override the toString() of the superclass";
    }

    @Override public String toString123() {
       return "Override the toString123() of the superclass";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }


}
```

Annotation declaration for `Override` just gets compiled to,

```
interface java.lang.Override extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation{
}
```

which is nothing more than an `interface`.

So,

How does `interface java.lang.Override` syntax help java compiler to detect above error at compile time?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The `@Override` annotation does **nothing**. It merely indicates to the compiler that you intend that method to override something. The compiler then errors out if it doesn't. You seem to have that covered - what are you actually asking?

Comment: @BoristheSpider How can I do the same work by declaring`@interface Ioverride`?

Comment: That is a **completely** different question. Is it not?

Comment: @BoristheSpider If I get an answer for my question above, then I can write my own annotation `@interface Ioverride`. that is my intention of this question.

Comment: @overexchange If that's what you were looking for, that's what you should be asking. As it stands, the question is *How does interface java.lang.Override syntax help java compiler to detect above error at compile time?* and not *How do I write my own custom annotation like @Override.* Please edit your question to make it clear. That being said, there are plenty of articles out there which already explain how to do this. **See my answer!!**

Comment: You need to write an _annotation processor_ and ask javac to run it when it compiles.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Where do I locate the annotation processor for `@Override` annotation in jdk code?

Comment: Annotations in the java.lang package are handled directly by `javac`, without the use of an annotation processor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implementation that triggers the compile error doesn't lie in the annotation, it lies in the Java compiler.

If you want to write your own similar annotation processor, you would use the annotation processor API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html

Comment: If I need to declare my own `@interface Ioverride` that checks overriding at compile time, How do I do that?

Comment: @overexchange He's just answered that.

Comment: @overexchange This answer has pretty much covered both parts of your question. If you want detailed examples though, take a look at my answer for some relevant articles on the internet..

Answer (score 5):

> which is nothing more than an interface.
>
> So,
>
> How does interface java.lang.Override syntax help java compiler to
>   detect above error at compile time?

That's right. `Override` is nothing more than an interface. The actual work is done by the java compiler. How the compiler does this is not specified.

Here are some links that explain how to work with an `AnnotationProcessor` to implement something similar to `@Override` :

1. [Processor Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html)
2. [Java annotation processing tool](http://www.visma.com/blog/java-annotation-processing-tool-tips-writing-testing/)
3. [Code generation using AnnotationProcessor](https://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/)
4. [Annotation Processor, generating a compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959728/annotation-processor-generating-a-compiler-error)
5. [Source code analysis using Java 6 API](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/10/source-code-analysis-using-java-6-compiler-apis.html)
6. [Playing with Java annotation processing](http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/playing-with-java-annotation-processing.html)